# dont understand how to eliminate the parameter t

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a linear algebra book but I am stuck.I do not quite understand the steps that the author got to so I'm asking how does he get 7x + 5y = 35. I know you have to eliminate the variable but I do not get the same answer.

[image: this shows what im talking about]

I have searched google but I could not find what I was looking for so i hope someone can tell me what steps to get to the answer this will help me alot because im trying to do computer graphics programming and i want to learn it linear algebra but im i keep getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$x=5t;\qquad y=7-7t.$$
From the first equation, we get
$$t=\frac{x}{5}.$$
Substituting this into the second one,
\begin{align*}y&=7-7t\\
y&=7-7\frac{x}{5}\\
5y&=35-7x\\
7x+5y&=35.\end{align*}

Comment: It is equation (12) in the image not (14) but as the text in the image says you will really get the same answer.

Comment: so by eliminating fractions ill get the answer sorry if this seems basic

Comment: @user2245494 you're just solving one equation for $t$ and then substituting that value of $t$ into the other equation

Comment: ok i understand now thanks

Comment: @user2245494 no problem. I've edited the answer so I'm solving (12) rather than (14)

Answer (score 0):

You are given
$$
x=5t,\qquad
\text{and}\qquad
y=7-7t.
$$
You want to eliminate the parameter $t$. Multiply $x$ by $7$ to get
$$
7x=35t\tag{$\ast$}
$$
and mutiply $y$ by $5$ to get
$$
5y=35-35t\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
Now substitute $(\ast)$ into $(\ast\ast)$ to get

$$
5y=35-7x\Rightarrow 7x+5y=35
$$